# simplexml_load_file('$variable') - variable url from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, variables, simplexml

I hope comeone could help me out with my problem.

I have mysql table where is are columns ID and XMLLink, there is only one row which is UPDATED  via `html/php/mysql` form..

My problem is I need to get data from XMLLink to some variable and this variable echo out in `simplexml_load_file('$variable')`
I don't know if is this even possible but I try it..

I have this code:

```
$xmllink_query = mysql_query("SELECT xmllink FROM {$cfg[tbl_xmllink]} WHERE id='1'") or die(mysql_error());

while ($xmllink_array = mysql_fetch_row($xmllink_query)){
    $xmllink    =$xmllink_array['0'];

}
echo $xmllink;
//simplexml load xml feed file
   $vmdily =  simplexml_load_file('$xmllink');
```

When I echo out only `$xmllink` it works fine but I'm getting error like `Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "$xmllink"`

How is possible to resolve this?

Thank you for your suggestions. :)

Comment: get rid of the quotation: simplexml_load_file($xmllink);

Comment: I agree with @axel.michel but I have another question.. why would you use an iteration if you are just getting the last element?

Comment: Just don't loop and get the value directly from the DB. Don't use an array

Comment: Thank you all! I don't know why I didnt try it.. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to replace  `$vmdily =  simplexml_load_file('$xmllink');` with  `$vmdily =  simplexml_load_file($xmllink);`

just remove `''` from `('$xmllink')`

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes or remove them completely

```
$vmdily =  simplexml_load_file("$xmllink");
```